# Facebook Login Blank Screen In Production

Tags: reactjs, facebook, facebook-login

I'm using the [react-facebook-login](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-facebook-login) library to implemented the facebook login in my react application. Every time I click on the facebook login button to try to login, it gives me a blank page for some reason. Once I close the popup it logs in automatically to my account. This is only happening in production, everything is working fine on localhost. I checked the url bellow to see if there's a problem with the app id but there wasn't.

here's a screenshot of the popup page:

[image]

and here's the url:

[https://www.facebook.com/v2.3/dialog/oauth?app_id=[app_id]&auth_type=&cbt=1662983366825&channel_url=https%3A%2F%2Fstaticxx.facebook.com%2Fx%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter%2F%3Fversion%3D46%23cb%3Df3167cf29f7288c%26domain%3Ddash.indepth.inkylab.com%26is_canvas%3Dfalse%26origin%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fdash.indepth.inkylab.com%252Ff304eb27eb1ffa4%26relation%3Dopener&client_id=[client_id]&display=popup&domain=dash.indepth.inkylab.com&e2e=%7B%7D&fallback_redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdash.indepth.inkylab.com%2Fdashboard%2Foverview%2F&locale=en_US&logger_id=f1c467f11696cbc&origin=1&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fstaticxx.facebook.com%2Fx%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter%2F%3Fversion%3D46%23cb%3Df11d4365f6ca06%26domain%3Ddash.indepth.inkylab.com%26is_canvas%3Dfalse%26origin%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fdash.indepth.inkylab.com%252Ff304eb27eb1ffa4%26relation%3Dopener%26frame%3Df36d6c5766d6e5&response_type=token%2Csigned_request%2Cgraph_domain&return_scopes=false&scope=public_profile%2Cpages_show_list%2Cread_insights%2Cpages_read_engagement%2Cpages_read_user_content&sdk=joey&version=v2.3](https://www.facebook.com/v2.3/dialog/oauth?app_id=%5Bapp_id%5D&auth_type=&cbt=1662983366825&channel_url=https%3A%2F%2Fstaticxx.facebook.com%2Fx%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter%2F%3Fversion%3D46%23cb%3Df3167cf29f7288c%26domain%3Ddash.indepth.inkylab.com%26is_canvas%3Dfalse%26origin%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fdash.indepth.inkylab.com%252Ff304eb27eb1ffa4%26relation%3Dopener&client_id=%5Bclient_id%5D&display=popup&domain=dash.indepth.inkylab.com&e2e=%7B%7D&fallback_redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdash.indepth.inkylab.com%2Fdashboard%2Foverview%2F&locale=en_US&logger_id=f1c467f11696cbc&origin=1&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fstaticxx.facebook.com%2Fx%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter%2F%3Fversion%3D46%23cb%3Df11d4365f6ca06%26domain%3Ddash.indepth.inkylab.com%26is_canvas%3Dfalse%26origin%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fdash.indepth.inkylab.com%252Ff304eb27eb1ffa4%26relation%3Dopener%26frame%3Df36d6c5766d6e5&response_type=token%2Csigned_request%2Cgraph_domain&return_scopes=false&scope=public_profile%2Cpages_show_list%2Cread_insights%2Cpages_read_engagement%2Cpages_read_user_content&sdk=joey&version=v2.3)

component:

```js
                <FacebookLogin
                    appId={appId}
                    autoLoad={false}
                    scope={permissions.join(',')}
                    fields="name,email,picture"
                    onClick={handleClick}
                    callback={handleResponse}
                    render={renderProps => (
                        <div className="fb-login" onClick={renderProps.onClick}>
                            <img className="fb-login-logo" src="https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v3/yd/r/pXqmY8Ggh_m.png" />
                            <span className="fb-inner">&nbsp;&nbsp;Login with Facebook</span>
                        </div>
                    )}
                />
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Apparently you need to enable the login with the javascript sdk and specify the allowed domains. That was the problem for me. Settings can be found in facebook login product settings.

[image]

Comment: For me (not using the SDK), the problem was I didn't have "Valid OAuth Redirect URIs" listed. Once I added those, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had my app created for a while and when I've tried set it up for Facebook Login for business I encounter this blank screen issue, even everything seemed setup. After 2 days of struggling the solution was to create another new app in my account and IT WORKED... with the same settings.
Maybe it will help.